# Ol start is not workign in birt

Tags: birt

ol with start attribute not working

```
<ol start="5"> <li>test item</li></ol>
```

Birt omitting start attribute in Ol tag if specified. And the list item always starts with 1

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question actually.
BIRT does not support the whole HTML specification and there are no plans to change this.

Comment: May I request pull request. I already made a changes in source code.